# Dynamic input masking for numbers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf

How can a mask be created, that at first displays as an integer, but if the user enters a "." it shows as decimal with 2 fractions?

This would create a mask with 2 fixed fractions:

```
<script>
    jQuery(function($){
       $("#digit").mask("99999.99");
   });
</script>
```

How can I make the count of numbers before the "." unlimited, and only show the dot if it is entered?

Comment: May be you can try this out? [meiomask](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/advanced-decimal-input-mask) Not sure what plugin you are currently using though..

Comment: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/ and https://github.com/plentz/jquery-maskmoney

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a very neat plugin which does all sort of decimal formatting:
http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/